# how to add video to tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, sdk, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to add (show all my video file)video file in row of Tableview and play it.but i don't know how to do it!

can you help me (I need to sample code)
thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at perhaps MPMoviePlayerController http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController then simply add the view to the row in a table view.

Comment: In your link for simple it's very short for understand because i begin start it.Have you other simple (I need to full sample (code in .h and .m) ) Thanks you agian

Comment: Now I don't to how to add vedio to cell in tableview

Comment: Get the view from your MPMoviePlayerController object, it's a property so a simple myMovieController.view would work. Then you would add that view to your tableView cell's view with an addSubview: method.